# Condition variables and real time priorities in pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads, thread-priority

I have two threads, a producer and a consumer. The producer thread recives data from another program through a named pipe at different rates, and forwards it to a consumer thread through a queue. The scheduler policy is RR and the producer thread has higher priority than the consumer thread. I want the producer to signal that there is new data on the queue, and have the consumer wait until the producer blocks, which will happen when there is no data to read from the named pipe.

The main thread sets the priorities:

```
policy = SCHED_FIFO;    

pthread_attr_init(&tattr);
pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&tattr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
pthread_attr_setscope(&tattr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&tattr, policy);

param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&tattr, &param);
pthread_create(&tid[0], &tattr, producer, fifo);

param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_min(policy);
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&tattr, &param);
pthread_create(&tid[1], &tattr, consumer, fifo);
```

The producer does this:

```
fd = open(pipe, O_RDONLY);
while((read(fd, buf, 1024))!=0){
    val = atoi(buf);
    if(val > SOMETHING){
        do_something();
    } else {
        pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut);
        while (fifo->full) {
            pthread_cond_wait (fifo->notFull, fifo->mut);
        }
        queueAdd (fifo, val);
        pthread_mutex_unlock (fifo->mut);
        pthread_cond_signal (fifo->notEmpty);
    }
}
```

The consumer:

```
while(TRUE){
    pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut);
    while (fifo->empty) {
        pthread_cond_wait (fifo->notEmpty, fifo->mut);
    }
    queueDel (fifo, &d);
    do_something_else(d);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (fifo->mut);
    pthread_cond_signal (fifo->notFull);
}
```

After the signaling, the lower priority thread takes over. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Changed the names of the threads. I had changed the names when posting it here, because my code is in spanish and the function names are something other than producer consumer, and made a mistake. But unluckily it's not that simple.

What I mean by 'takes over' is that the consumer continues execution. What I want is for it to start if and only if the producer thread blocks or exits.

Comment: What do you mean by "the lower priority thread takes over"? Have you considered using message queue from mqueue.h header to transfer data to consumer, and signal the producer with a single condition variable + shared volatile variable or maybe a semaphore or a signal?

Comment: No, I have not tried that. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: So, to be clear, you only want the consumer to run if the FIFO is non-empty *and* the producer cannot run (e.g. is stuck in the blocking `read`)? As opposed to currently when it just runs if the former condition is met?

Comment: @asCii88 so hold the mutex around `do_something` too, so the only point at which the mutex is unlocked is when it is in `read` (I think that's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you were a little clearer about what you meant by 'the lower priority thread takes over' this would be easier to determine. But I don't think (with the code as it is) this has anything to do with scheduling policy.

From the POSIX spec (OK, from [The Single UNIX Specification, Version 2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_attr_setschedpolicy.html), but same difference):

> If more than one thread is blocked on a condition variable, the scheduling policy determines the order in which threads are unblocked. When each thread unblocked as a result of a `pthread_cond_signal()` or `pthread_cond_broadcast()` returns from its call to `pthread_cond_wait()` or `pthread_cond_timedwait()`, the thread owns the mutex with which it called `pthread_cond_wait()` or `pthread_cond_timedwait()`. The thread(s) that are unblocked contend for the mutex according to the scheduling policy (if applicable), and as if each had called `pthread_mutex_lock()`.

Now, because of your mutex ordering (see comment in final paragraph), the other thread does not hold the mutex when `pthread_cond_signal` is performed. So, on a single CPU machine, we know it's going to get scheduled in regardless of scheduling policy, so the signalled thread will instantly grab the mutex, before the signalling thread manages to relock it. IE as only one thread is contending for the mutex at the time, the scheduling policy is irrelevant, and it will always get it.

Is this what you are referring to?

Also, if `do_something_else(d);` is in the slightest time-consuming, you don't want to do that with the mutex held, or it will stop the producer running.

It's possible that there is another thing at play here. Another problem might be that your `pthread_cond_signal` is not working because of a race condition. You don't *have* to call `pthread_cond_signal` with the mutex held, but it is a good idea IMHO. In this instance, for instance, in the consumer you unlock the mutex after removing something from the queue, then do the signal. Between dropping the mutex and making the signal the FIFO may have changed state, and referring to `fifo->notFull` is technically unsafe. I suggest swapping the `pthread_mutex_unlock` and the `pthread_cond_signal` around; this may also improve scheduling.

## EDIT

*Now redundant as this was the OP's error, since fixed*

<s>Is this actually really simple? In your original message you say:</s>

> The scheduler policy is RR and the producer thread has higher priority than the consumer thread.

However in your code:

```
param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&tattr, &param);
pthread_create(&tid[0], &tattr, consumerr, fifo);

param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_min(policy);
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&tattr, &param);
pthread_create(&tid[1], &tattr, producer, fifo);
```

Which looks to me like it's the *consumer* which is given maximum priority, and the producer which is given the minimum.

Comment: unlocking of mutex and signaling the condition variable are in perfectly good order in the original code. You will find info everywhere that doing what you suggest if "pessimization", and results in nothing more than excessive context switches. You don't use mutex to synchronize access to condition variable, but to protect shared resources.

Comment: As I said, there's nothing to require that the mutex is held when the condition variable is signalled, *but* that doesn't relieve you of the requirement to synchronising access to variables. However, I think I am correct that the OP's ordering will always result in the thread waiting on that mutex getting it, which will always result in a context switch if the next thing the signalling thread does (like here) is wait on the mutex (see start of next `while` loop); if there is only one thing waiting on a mutex, it will get it. Whether it's optimal or pessimal depends on the circumstance.

Comment: There will be an immediate context switch. But in your scenario there will be... an immediate context switch even earlier. If you hold the mutex while signaling the condition, the signaled thread wakes up, and "inside" the `wait` function blocks on mutex, which results in another context switch back to the signaling thread, which can then unlock the mutex, so another context switch to the signaled thread. This _is_ pessimization, because this way you ALWAYS get these extra switches, and in opposite case - only when you have a loop like the OP - the context switch is expected in that case.

Comment: And as for the problem, we still don't know what does it mean to "take over", so it's not possible to solve the problem stated that precisely (;

Comment: @FreddieChopin not sure you are right there. From the standard (see link above): `however, if predictable scheduling behaviour is required, then that mutex is locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_signal() or pthread_cond_broadcast().` - unless they are suggesting pessimal == predictable! I believe the mutex handling works like for the `pthread_cond_wait` under this circumstance, i.e. it is treated for scheduling as if the mutex is dropped. Anyway, we should probably not be arguing about this in the comments.

Comment: @FreddieChopin I *think* he meant the consumer (the lower priority thread) gets all the CPU time.

Comment: But it's not possible in the code he showed - eventually the queue would become empty, and the consumer would wait for the queue to be filled with at least one element... Everything should work as expected... Unless you expect something wrong, but we don't know that...

Comment: I'm not sure if the site informs that I have edited the question, so I'm posting here just to let you know, you can take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your project with optimizations *DISABLED*, because if you have them enabled right now and the variables fifo->empty and fifo->full are *NOT* declared volatile, then there is a big possibility that compiler optimizes some parts of your code in a way that you wouldn't like - the value is tested only once, and if it is true your code falls into an endless loop (the one with `pthread_cond_wait()`) that it will not leave no matter what, because compiler cannot see how `pthread_cond_wait()` could alter it.

If that's not it, then the behavior you describe is still not clear to me... Your example should work in the following way:

- producer puts something in the queue until it's full, then blocks,
- consumer takes the item from the queue, and signals the producer that there is one free slot,
- producer wakes up (assuming it's not blocked on `read()`) and puts one item into the queue (that's the whole free space), then blocks,
- ...

How is the behavior you see different from what you expect? How can consumer "take over" when there's no data in the queue? It should stop "taking over" after the first (which is also the last) element taken from the queue and wait for producer to add anything.

Comment: When the producer puts something in the queue and signals pthread_cond_signal (fifo->notEmpty), the consumber unblocks, takes the element, and runs. Of course, when there's nothing left in the queue, which is after one iteration, it blocks and the producer runs again.